# Linear regression to predict the y-value for the trend series

Tags: javascript, timestamp, linear-regression

I have [x,y] pairs where x value is in Unix- time values and y in float. I am needing to find the best fit line for this series. I am using the linear regression model as in this link below:

http://dracoblue.net/dev/linear-least-squares-in-javascript/159/

I am getting the values correctly. But, Since my x-data is in unix timestamp, I get really huge values. So, has any one got any suggestions on how to tone it down? I tried using seconds instead of milliseconds, by diving the x-data by 1000. But, that just makes the difference in the final y-values very negligible and I don't see a proper trendline.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,S.

Comment: POSIX time_t values (aka Unix timestamps) are already in units of seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it start at 0 : substract each occurence of a x value by what was the first x (say x0) value.

For instance, line 31 of your link :
replace `x = values_x[v];` with `x = values_x[v] - values_x[0];`
If values_x is ordered and ascending then it should be ok

Comment: You mean subtract the x with the previous x values? Like x[i]=xVal[i]-xVal[i-1]?

Comment: Nope, substract it with the first value ! See I edited my answer, try it and tell me

Comment: That did the track! Thanks tons =)

Answer (score 1):

Can you subtract the first x value to the entire series so that the x start from 0?